# Errors bootstrapping pkgsrc on RHEL5.2

Tags: linux

I'm trying to build pkgsrc on RHEL 5.2 using:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=$HOME/$( uname -m )/pkg --unprivileged
```

I burned some time tracking down an error caused by having MAKEFLAGS set to "--no-print-directory" (useful with gnu-make, but an error with bmake, and bmake's phenomenally useful feature of printing a usage statement instead of erroring out with an indication of the unrecognized option put me in a bit of a mood) and suspect that the current problem is something similar.

The bootstrap runs to completion, but the only file that gets installed is `${prefix}/etc/mk.conf`.  The `make install` in pkgtools/pkg_install does not actually do anything (but it succeeds and emits no errors).  The command that bootstrap runs (that does nothing) is:

```
${wrkdir}/bin/bmake USE_DESTDIR=no -DPKG_PRESERVE \
    MAKECONF=${wrkdir}/mk.conf install
```

If I add a `-n`, I see exactly one line of output: `true`.
If I remove the `-DPKG_PRESERVE MAKECONF=${wrkdir}/mk.conf` arguments, the install appears to succeed and ${prefix} is populated with files as expected.  Similarly if I set `MAKECONF=/dev/null`.  Since `${wrkdir}/mk.conf` is built by bootstrap and looks pretty innocuous (it is just 10 variable assignments), my question is: what's wrong with it?  Are the files that get installed when not using those assignments useful?  And, mostly, what might there be in my environment that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Arghhh.  I had BUILD_DIR defined.  Perhaps the documentation should specify running:

```
env -i ./bootstrap ...
```